# Why "DIV EDX" in MASM always generates processor exception?

Tags: exception, assembly, x86, division

I've got that question on my Computer Architecture Exam on Informatics last semester :
*"Why 'DIV EDX' in MASM always generates processor exception?"*
What is the mechanism which generates exception?

Comment: It has nothing to do with MASM, btw. And the mechanism is the CPU.

Comment: [Is the i386 instruction "div ah" pointless?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63273843) is basically a duplicate of this, but that question asks why it's even encodeable.  (because no need to special case it to #UD instead of #DE).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you do 1-operand division on x86 CPUs, EDX:EAX (64 bit) is divided by the 1st operand (32 bit). The result is stored in EAX (32 bit).

So when you divide by EDX:EAX by EDX, what you essentially get is (EDX * 0x100000000 + EAX) / EDX, which result is always above 0x100000000 and does not fit into the target register or the divisor is zero. In both cases a divide exception occurs.

See also [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20120606081847/http://siyobik.info.gf/main/reference/instruction/DIV) (from the Intel developer manuals).

Note that this is not specific to the assembler (MASM), but to the platform in this case.